# MySQL any fix for query?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm currently trying to code a timekeeping-software and I need to fetch the data from a mysql-database, but my current query (below) is somehow flawed:


A table called timekeeping has following columns: 

1. name of employee as varchar,

2. name of event ("checkin", "checkout") as varchar,

3. timestamp of that event


I (want to) retrieve a table from this table that gives me following columns:

1. name of employee as varchar/string

2. check-in-timestamp as timestamp

3. check-out-timestamp as timestamp

4. hours (of the time difference) as int

5. remaining minutes (of the time difference) as int


**If there is a check-in, but no check-out before the next check-in:** 
The check-out-column-entry shall be null (so the employer sees that the employee forgot to check-out).


**If there is a check-out, but no check-in right before that check-out:** 
The check-in-column-entry shall be null (so the employer sees that the employee forgot to check-in).


 **Problem:** 

If an employee checks in, works till noon and then checks out for a break then later checks back in and checks out after a while my current query only calculates the time difference of the FIRST check-in and LAST Check-out which is obviously wrong...

> Also: it calculates these only if these check-ins and check-outs
>   happen within one date, which is not that big of an issue (but
>   imagine timekeeping right before midnight and right after midnight...
>   currently impossible)

Also the check-ins and check-outs inbetween the first check-in and check-out are not even displayed anywhere (so missing rows)...

My current (wrong) query:

```
SELECT Employee, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN event = 'checkin' THEN timestamp END) as checkin,
       MAX(CASE WHEN event = 'checkout' THEN timestamp END) as checkout,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, 
             MIN(CASE WHEN event = 'checkin' THEN timestamp END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN event = 'checkout' THEN timestamp END)
       ) AS hours,
       MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
             MIN(CASE WHEN event = 'checkin' THEN timestamp END),
             MAX(CASE WHEN event = 'checkout' THEN timestamp END)
       ), 60) AS minutes
FROM timekeeping AS T
WHERE employee LIKE 'Bobby Brown'
GROUP BY Date(timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

**EDIT:**

**Example:** 
 Lets say an employee checks in at 6 o'clock, works, goes away for a break at 12 but doesn't check-out, then comes back at 13 and checks in, works till 15 and checks out. My query will return only one entry from 6 to 15

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually do these kinds of subqueries, but it is worth a shot:

```
SELECT T_in.Employee
, T_in.timestamp AS checkin
, (SELECT MIN(T_out.timestamp) 
   FROM timekeeping AS T_out
   WHERE T_out.employee = T_in.employee 
     AND T_out.timestamp > T_in.timestamp
     AND T_out.event = 'checkout'
  ) AS checkout
FROM timekeeping AS T_in
WHERE T_in.employee LIKE 'Bobby Brown' 
  AND T_in.event = 'checkin'
ORDER BY checkin
;
```

And to get the timespan, do something like this:

```
SELECT Employee, checkin, checkout
  , ((TIME_TO_SEC(checkout) - TIME_TO_SEC(checking)) / 60)
    + (DATEDIFF(DATE(checkout), DATE(checkin)) * 60 * 24) 
    AS `minutes`
FROM (
  [the query above minus the ;]
) AS subQ
;
```

Edit: Added actual minutes calculation; note that 60 * 24 is the number of minutes in a day (the TIME_TO_SEC() subtraction portion will be negative if crossing midnight).

Edit2: This should help with the in-in-out scenario.

```
( SELECT T_in.Employee
, T_in.timestamp AS checkin
, (SELECT IF(T_out.event = 'checkout', T_out.timestamp, NULL) 
   FROM timekeeping AS T_out
   WHERE T_out.employee = T_in.employee 
     AND T_out.timestamp > T_in.timestamp
   ORDER BY T_out.timestamp ASC
   LIMIT 1
  ) AS checkout
FROM timekeeping AS T_in
WHERE T_in.employee LIKE 'Bobby Brown' 
  AND T_in.event = 'checkin'
ORDER BY checkin ) AS sub1
UNION (
SELECT T_out2.Employee
, (SELECT IF(T_in2.event = 'checkin', T_in2.timestamp, NULL) 
   FROM timekeeping AS T_in2
   WHERE T_in2.employee = T_out2.employee 
     AND T_in2.timestamp < T_out2.timestamp
   ORDER BY T_in2.timestamp DESC
   LIMIT 1) AS checkin
, T_out2.timestamp AS checkout 
FROM timekeeping AS T_out2
WHERE T_out2.employee LIKE 'Bobby Brown' 
  AND T_out2.event = 'checkout'
HAVING checkin IS NULL ) AS sub2
;
```

*Last edit done on a tablet, so I hope that is right. ;)*

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Your query is good and returns all adjoining check-ins and check-outs (and their time differences), but it won't return those entries which either don't have a corresponding check-out or check-in... can we somehow correct that?!

Comment: Like I said, I am not well acquainted with subqueries like this (the "checkout" one that is). I would've thought it would return null, not eliminated the outer result row. Perhaps someone more familiar with them can get it closer to what you need. (I do know something can be worked out `UNION`ing with a couple `LEFT JOIN` queries; I'll check back later and if no one has responded add that.)

Comment: Thanks, hopefully somehow we will get it working... Example: Lets say an employee checks in at 6 o'clock, works, goes away for a break at 12 but doesn't check-out, then comes back at 13 and checks in, works till 15 and checks out. Your query will return the entry of 13 till 15 but won't return the first 6 hours (which do not have a checkout). My query will return one entry from 6 to 15... help...!

Comment: Pardon me! Your query returns two entries! One from 6 to 15 and one from 13 to 15. Still wrong, but I wanted you to know

Comment: Ah, I was assuming the system would not allow that kind of situation. Most timekeepers I dealt with required a checkout before another checkin could be made. You might be able to get somewhere converting that subquery to an "ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 1"  (or two? one for the actual `timestamp`, another for the `event`). Oh, hold on...

Comment: GREAT! Your query (Edit 2) works almost perfectly! The only problem I see now: If an employee forgot to make a check-in at the very first timekeeping-day, but made a check-out later that day, your query won't show this entry at all. It should show a row where the check-in is null

Comment: Sorry, I need to correct myself again: your query (edit 2) won't ever show any rows where the check-in should be null. So if an employee forgets to check-in there won't be any visible rows that show this to the employer... damn

Comment: Oh and there was a mistake in your third line ", (SELECT IF(T_out.event = 'checkout', eventT_out.timestamp, NULL) ". I guess you didn't mean "eventT_out.timestamp "? I corrected it to T_out.timestamp

Comment: Yeah. That was a typo. I'll add a union to include the outs without ins.

Comment: Thank you, this works flawlessly ! Every entry is recognized, no matter if the employee forgot to check-in/check-out! The only thing I changed: delete the "AS sub1" and "AS sub2" because that gave some errors